# Prove that $f$ having a limit at $0$ implies that $f$ has a limit at every real number

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Assume $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ ( The class of exponential functions has this property). Prove that $f$ having a limit at $0$ implies that $f$ has a limit at every real number and is one, or $f$ is identically $0$ for every $ x \in \mathbb{R}$

This is what I have so far. I know we can demonstrate this using the exponential function where $$f(0)=a^0=1$$ 
Hence $$f(x+0)=f(x)f(0)=a^x*a^0=a^x=f(x)$$ 
If $f$ is continuous at $0$ then $$\lim_{h\to 0}f(x+h)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(x)f(h)=f(x)$$
Making $f$ continuous.

Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Exactly the same. Forget the $a$

Comment: What? I don't follow what you are trying to say

Comment: Like how would I continue this?

Comment: You don't actually have to assume it's an exponential function, so you can remove all the parts that use $a^x$.

Comment: Ohhh I get it. Thanks :)

Comment: But How would I prove the second part?

Answer (score 1):

For the second, set $y=0$ and get $\forall xf(x)=f(x)f(0)$.  If there is any number $x$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$ we get that $f(0)=1$

Comment: Isn't that quite similar to the method I have used?

Comment: @math101:  yes, but it seemed you were asking about it in your last comment "how would I prove the second part".  Maybe I got the wrong second part.

Comment: What does it mean that f is identically $0$ for $ x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @math101:  that is a perfectly good function.  No matter what $x$ you feed it, $f(x)=0$.  In this proof, it means I can't find an $x$ so I can divide by $f(x)$, so the proof that $f(0)=1$ fails.  A good thing, because $f(0)=0$.